# How to read "20.00 Uhr"

Tags: pronunciation

> Heute Abend essen wir erst um 20.00 Uhr.

How does one read the "20.00" Uhr out loud? Is it "zwanzig Uhr" or "zwanzig Punkt null null Uhr"?

Comment: Wir essen schon um acht.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would omit the zeros.

> Heute Abend essen wir erst um zwanzig Uhr.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. For this case you would normally omit the zeros, as you don't expect people to be there on the minute. So it is (as Lars pointed out)

> Heute Abend essen wir erst um zwanzig Uhr.

If you were to eat at 19.30, you'll have to say:

> Heute Abend essen wir um neunzehn Uhr dreissig.

oder

> Heute Abend essen wir um halb acht.

The following is *not* commonly used though:

> Heute Abend essen wir um neunzehn dreissig Uhr.

If it is really important that it is exactly 20.00, then you would say:

> Der Zug fährt im Hauptbahnhof um zwanzig Uhr null null ab.

Comment: Note that if your information is not supposed to be precise to the minute, you should also omit the zeros in writing (though many people use zeros were they shouldn’t.). Also, if you want to emphasise thatthe information is precise to the minute, you would rather use *Punkt zwanzig Uhr* instead of *zwanzig Uhr null null.*

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Yea, agreed. In conversation definitely. But if you say "zwanzig Uhr null fünf" it is usually obvious that you mean to be precise.

Comment: It will be understood, yes. But I never heard anybody actually use it.

Comment: Well, the anouncements at the train station are always exactly this way here.

Comment: I was going to answer: Deutsche Bahn is not a good reference for any language, but then I saw where you are located …